# How to cope with diacritics while trying to match with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

Trying to use regular expression with unicode html escapes for diacritics:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
htmlstring=u'''/">čćđš</a>.../">España</a>'''

print re.findall( r'/">(.*?)</a', htmlstring, re.U )
```

produces :

```
[u'\u010d\u0107\u0111\u0161', u'Espa\xf1a']
```

Any help, please?

Comment: are you running python3? If yes, then use regex module `regex.findall(r"/\">(.*?)</a", htmlstring)`

Comment: @Avinash no, thank you for asking. It's 2.7.

Comment: When you print a list, its elements are `repr`ed, that's why you see `\uXXXX` stuff instead of letters. There's nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an encoding question. Your code is working as it should. Were you expecting something different? Your strings that are prefixed with `u` are unicode literals. The characters that begin with `\u` are unicode characters followed by four hex digits, whereas the characters that begin with `\x` are unicode characters followed by only two hex digits. If you print out your results (instead of looking at their `__repr__` method), you will see that you have received the result that it appears you were looking for:

```
results = [u'\u010d\u0107\u0111\u0161', u'Espa\xf1a']
for result in results:
    print result

čćđš
España
```

In your code (i.e. in your list), you see the representation of these unicode literals:

```
for result in results:
    print result.__repr__()

u'\u010d\u0107\u0111\u0161'        # what shows up in your list
u'Espa\xf1a'
```

Incidentally, it appears that you are trying to parse html with regexes. You should try [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or something similar instead. It will save you a major headache down the road.

Comment: Yes, I worked with bs4, but considered that should be a piece of cake even without it :)

Comment: @Alex Great. I'm glad you know about. In very simple scenarios, `BeautifulSoup` can certainly be overkill. Cheers.